# Motorcycle frame slider bolt breaking off too often

Tags: motorcycle, fastener

I use Puig R12 frame sliders on my Yamaha R3 motorcycle. The frame sliders are held in place by **12.9 grade stainless steel** bolts (https://www.boltdepot.com/fastener-information/materials-and-grades/bolt-grade-chart.aspx) such as the ones below:

[image]

I got my frame sliders just 2 week ago and the bolts holding the left frame slider has broken off 2 times in that duration! I was wondering what the issue could be. Also, what sort of bolt grades can I get that is more resistant to breaking off? The frame sliders coming off due to breaking bolts makes them quite useless if my bike was to fall off. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Get some bolts that are grade 8 or better, anodised or black finish...

Comment: @SolarMike The black finish bolts same as mild steel bolts (as opposed to stainless steel)? Are they less prone to breaking off?

Comment: Check out what grade 8 means, they should be stronger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grade 12.9 is a low alloy steel , not stainless, although that is not a problem. The  12.9 strength level is exceptionally high . That high hardness makes them prone to cracking during electro-plating unless conditions are very well controlled. They are also subject to cracking during heat-treatment.  I think there is a good chance there was a small crack/defect in them originally. Possibly they were over-torqued or an EP lube was used during installation when not recommended. I would try a lower strength fastener like Grade 8 which will need to be torqued to a lower level.

Comment: Thanks. I will go with Grade 8 now. Is grade 8 prone to breakage if over torqued as well?

Comment: If over torqued, yes.  Here's a chart with recommended torque values: http://www.gtsparkplugs.com/bolt-torque-chart-metric.html

Comment: Check the lube used for the torque tables. If EP lubes ( like moly sulfide) are used  and were not listed in the tables , they could be over torqued.